# How to backup Nvidia Control Panel preferences?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

Every now and then I have to perform a fresh reinstallation of Nvidia drivers. This always results in losing all configuration settings.
According to [this post](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/914268/geforce-drivers/export-import-nvidia-control-panel-settings-and-color-profiles/post/4796732/#4796732) Control Panel preferences are stored in `nvdrsdb0.bin` and `nvdrsdb1.bin` files in `~/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/Drs`, but I don't know what is stored in the files and whether overwriting after driver installation is safe. I only want to export user configuration settings and nothing else.

[image: Nvidia Control Panel screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

[Nvidia Inspector](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/nvidia-inspector-download.html) can export and import Nvidia profile settings. Start "profile inspector" by clicking the icon on the right side, on the middle:

[image: Nvidia Inspector]

Select "export user defined profiles" (import option is next on the right), "export all customized profiles" option exports per-program settings:

[image: profile inspector]

Close Nvidia Control Panel before importing, if running.

Comment: there's no "profile inspector" icon there anymore

Comment: @MaximMazurok Comment noted, sadly I don't use Windows or own Nvidia hardware anymore.

Comment: here's a screenshot of the most recent version: https://i.imgur.com/pDpoY46.png the redstrike answer worked for me

Comment: @MaximMazurok Thank you, unaccepted the answer. I should've added a disclaimer about the risks for "importing" driver (or any low-level) settings.

Answer (score 4):

Use [NVIDIA Profile Inspector](https://github.com/Orbmu2k/nvidiaProfileInspector) to export and import NVIDIA Control Panel's customized profiles.

1. Download the latest stable version from its official GitHub repo: [nvidiaProfileInspector.zip](https://github.com/Orbmu2k/nvidiaProfileInspector/releases/latest/)
2. Unzip and run the app
3. Click `Export all customized profiles` in the dropdown menu

[image: Click Export user defined profiles]

4. Click `Select All` to check all customized profiles, then click `Export` button

[image]

5. Finally, choose a safe place and set a name for the backup file before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to export user configuration settings and nothing else.

Currently the Nvidia Control Panel has no mechanic to export the user's configuration settings.

You only have two options if you want to keep your settings from a previous or existing profile.

- Don't select the option to delete your previous settings when you updated your Nvidia drivers.
- Backup nvdrsdb0.bin and nvdrsdb1.bin before you select the option to clean your settings and then restore nvdrsdb0.bin and nvdrsdb1.bin after the installation is complete.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add new information, sorry.